# Strip Image Classes from HTML Output

Tags: php, images

Does anyone know how to remove all of this from the image HTML?

```
class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-31053"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at [get_image_tag()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_image_tag) which can take a lot of parameters like `$id`, `$alt`, `$title`, `$align`, `$size`.

If you look even closer you'll find the `get_image_tag_class` filter to change the image class names (like class, ID, align and size).

You can use the filter within your `functions.php` like this:

Note: This will still return an empty tag like: `class=""`

```
function strip_image_class($class, $id, $align, $size) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', 'strip_image_class', 0, 4);
```

Update: To completely remove everything related to the class you'll have to filter the `$html`:

```
function strip_entire_image_class($html) {
    return preg_replace('/ class="(.*)"/', '', $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'strip_entire_image_class', 0, 4);
```